# Blender suddenly stop working when I want to render

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, modifiers

am new to blender, I start a simple project on blender but suddenly it will stop working and closed the software program most of the part which happens is when rendering, opening a new file of 2d animation, modeling.
The blender version is 2.83

Comment: Does this happen with a specific file or every file?

Comment: No, it just closed by itself

Comment: What's your pc specifics? Are you using cpu or gpu for rendering? Did you tried with the brand new 2.83.1?

Comment: I used CPU to rendering

Comment: What are your pc specifics? Did you tried with the brand new 2.83.1?

Comment: What did you mean by my PC specific, but I am using blender version 2.83.1

Comment: I mean what's your cpu, your gpu, how much ram do you have...?

Comment: My system information windows 7 ultimate, Intel(R) core(TM)2 Duo CPU T7500 2.20GHz RAM 2GB system type 64bit operating system

Comment: Do you have a GPU? Are you rendering on CPU?

Comment: Am rendering on CPU